# Why if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-5x^2+2$, then $\mathcal O_{\Bbb Q[\alpha]}=\mathbb Z[\alpha]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to show that if $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-5x^2+2$ and $K=\Bbb Q[\alpha]$, then $\mathcal O_K=\Bbb Z[\alpha]$. This is homework, and one of the previous exercises asks to show that if we define $disc(\Bbb Z[\alpha])=disc(1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1})$, then $$disc(\Bbb Z[\alpha])=[\mathcal O_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]]^2disc(\mathcal O_K).$$

So I guess what has to be done is to show that $disc(\Bbb Z[\alpha])=disc(\mathcal O_K)$. However I can't see why this is true.

What I want is a HINT on how to solve this problem. Please DO NOT post a full answer. I have only read Neukirch's Algebraic Number theory until section 3 of chapter 1, so I would like to know a hint only using what I know so far.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: do not use Neukirch's book as a first excursion into algebraic number theory.

Comment: Why?, I think it's great!!

Comment: It is great after problems like computing the discriminant of a low degree extension have become trivial.  But when you have to think about a problem like the one you are posing, it means you need a more down to earth, computational introduction with emphasis on examples and approachable exercises.  Source: personal experience with trying to learn ANT for the first time from Neukirch, thinking I am sooo smart I can handle it.  It merely slowed down my progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is the discriminant of the cubic polynomial (why?), so you can compute it from the usual formula for the discriminant of a cubic polynomial.  The number you get is an integer.  It has to equal $[O_K:Z[a]]^2\textrm{disc}(O_K). $ Now what do you observe about this integer?

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @user203598 If you are still stuck after you compute this discriminant, I will continue the hint.

Comment: Ok, so I deduced that either $[\mathcal O_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]]=1$ or $[\mathcal O_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]]=2$.I can't see why we cannot have $[\mathcal O_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]]=2$.

Comment: Ok, I just used Stickelberg's identity.

Comment: @user203598 that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another argument, based partly on the ideas of @guest’s response. You find that the discriminant of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is $4$ times a prime, and you only want to know that the $4$ belongs there in the discriminant of $\mathscr O$. But look at your polynomial locally at $2$, where the Newton Polygon has its vertices at $(0,1)$, $(2,0)$, and $(3,0)$. In particular, the first slope is $-1/2$, requiring ramification at $2$ to get all the roots. So the discriminant must be divisible by $2$, and hence the $4$ needs to be there.

Comment: Very nice and more broadly applicable than the argument with Stickelberger's congruence.

Comment: Maybe it uses methods not familiar to OP, but it often helps to remember that the discriminant is the product of the local discs.